# How to show data using JSP/Expression Language in DataTables?

Tags: java, html, jsp, datatables

I am using `DataTables` in my client side page to show the data in a tabular form using some features of `DataTables` such as pagination and sorting. I am using DataTables CDN along with `JQuery`. It works if I show data like this `<td>Hello</td>`but if I use Expression Language DataTables doesn't show anything. I switched to chrome's developer view and found out that `<td>` tag is empty. So I want to know how can I use DataTables to show data?

JSP

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

 <table id="table_id" class="display">
  <thead>
        <tr>
              <th>Line of Business</th>
              <th>Customer Phone</th>
              <th>Customer Email</th>
        </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
        <tr>
              <c:forEach items="${intgList}" var="list">
                          <td><c:out value="${list.lob}"/></td>
                    </c:forEach>     
        </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready( function () {
            $('#table_id').DataTable();
        } );
```

So using F12 I could see that `<tr>` is empty. Am I doing anything wrong in here. Please let me know. Thanks...

Comment: Please show generated HTML from JSP. `ctrl+u`

Comment: I guess what `intgList` or `lob` is empty.

Comment: Alex, I can't produce it using JSFiddle but I will post it. I don't have my workspace right now. No intgList is not empty Alex. On browser it shows 

<tr> noting here </tr>

Comment: I dont need snippet, i need source code of compiled JSP.

Comment: That I can show you but as I said I don't have it with me right now. It looks like DataTables doesn't recognize the for each loop. You know if I do this 
<c:out value="HI"/> then it displays it.

Comment: Datables has no idea about foreach, are you a noobie in JSP?

Comment: Not a brand new but yes with DataTables.

Comment: If you look at the compiled JSP code, there should not be foreach

Comment: Documentation says that DataTables support JSP and I saw even one post here where someone had a for each loop and he didn't have complaints about it.

Comment: Datatables works with generated HTML.

Comment: Datatables could be feed via json.

Comment: Roman, honestly speaking I don't have much idea how to do it using JSON and I am not even suppose to change the logic too much you know. I am using DataTables because as per documentation as long as we play around with HTML tags for table it works.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit late but you have to do it like this:

```
    <c:forEach items="${IntgList}" var="list">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${list.example}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${list.example1}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${list.example2}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${list.example3}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${list.example4}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```